# WordPress theme like this Drupal theme?

Tags: wordpress, drupal, theme

I was wondering if anyone knew of a WordPress theme that was similar to this websites theme (in Drupal): http://www.barefootrunners.org

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know of one that is exactly like that, but I would try searching for magazine style wordpress themes. Those will have that similar type of layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at these WordPress themes @ http://themeforest.net/category/wordpress

There are dozens of themes that look similar.